# How to change the android:bottom at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, gradientdrawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

When set the  android:bottom="5dp" in the .xml，it works。But now, need to change the bottom value at runtime. With the debug , xml files was parsed to GradientDrawable. So, how to change the GradientDrawable, makes set the bottom value wokrs? thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setLayerInset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable#setLayerInset(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) . It accepts the layer index and 4 Offset values for each of sides .

```
setLayerInset(layer, leftOffset, topOffset, rightOffset, bottomOffset)
```

below is an example of modifying the bottom offset.

```
val layerDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.test) as LayerDrawable
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0,0,0,0,200)
imageView.background=layerDrawable
```

First argument is index of layer which you want to modify in this case there is only one layer so its 0 . Rest 4 values are in `pixels` So make sure you convert `DP` to `pixel` first when changing the offsets.

Comment: Thanks , it works for me!   Try to change  the `GradientDrawable` Object  makes me  wrong  at the beginning.